# run vlc in command line

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, vlc

So I have a Raspberry Pi 3+ running OctoPrint. I also have an HDMI IP camera attached to my 3D printer. Because the stream for the camera is not compatible, I have another server running the VLC command below. Is there a way I can run this command on the Raspberry Pi?

```
start  "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -R rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.44:554/videoMain --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mjpg,vb=2500,scale=1.0,fps=10,acodec=none}:standard{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=:8206/videostream.cgi}
```

This allows me to access the video like this:
http://192.168.1.3:8206/videostream.cgi

Answer (score 1):

No reason why not - refer to the Linux reference for VLC [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/).

As an example, this would stream using RTSP on port 8554 which you can view on any other device that can open network streams:

`raspivid -o - -t 99999 |cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}' :demux=h264`

You can replace this with whatever other protocol you want (I believe it's MJPEG that you have in the Windows cmd line).

As a side note, you can install [RPi-Cam-Web-Interface](https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) which is a far more feature-rich web server that is far easier to setup. Alternatively I've also had good success with [MJPEG-streamer](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-build-and-run-mjpg-streamer-on-the-raspberry-pi).